# How to achieve hidden overflow with css-only parallax?

Tags: css, scroll, overflow, parallax

There are a lot of resources about CSS-only parallax, but none that address my specific concern (or that I've found). Basically, I want slow scrolling elements to only be visible within their normal scrolling parents. In the following example, as the page is scrolled the normal scrolling white border should cleanly separate the slower scrolling images, but it only works in Chrome (version 52). Other browsers I've tested it in (FF and Safari) do not work:

```css
ul {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
     -webkit-perspective: 1px;
     -moz-perspective: 1px;
     perspective: 1px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: inherit;
    -moz-transform-style: inherit;
    transform-style: inherit;
}

li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

li div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="background-image: url(http://www.texturequalitypro.com/assets/files/content_files/TextureQualityPro_Large_Sample.jpg);"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="background-image: url(http://orig07.deviantart.net/fba3/f/2012/272/1/8/nikon_d600_image_sample_image__1__jpeg_large__by_mozlin-d5g7vbg.jpg);"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="background-image: url(http://archivision.com/educational/samples/files/1A2-F-P-I-2-C1_L.jpg);"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I understand that in the example the transform properties are not set correctly - the container UL has both the `perspective` and `transform-style` properties set (it should only have `perspective`), and the LI elements set `transform-style` to `inherit` instead of `preserve-3d` - however this is the only way I've been able to achieve the desired result, and only in Chrome.

(the images in the sample are not mine and I simply found them via a google search)

About the CSS transform properties, here is a "correct" example, but the images overlap each other:

```css
ul {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
     -webkit-perspective: 1px;
     -moz-perspective: 1px;
     perspective: 1px;
}
li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}

li div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="background-image: url(http://www.texturequalitypro.com/assets/files/content_files/TextureQualityPro_Large_Sample.jpg);"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="background-image: url(http://orig07.deviantart.net/fba3/f/2012/272/1/8/nikon_d600_image_sample_image__1__jpeg_large__by_mozlin-d5g7vbg.jpg);"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div style="background-image: url(http://archivision.com/educational/samples/files/1A2-F-P-I-2-C1_L.jpg);"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Uncommenting the `overflow: hidden` property on the LI element, which you might think will get the effect I want, breaks the parallax.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same issue as well. I have a live website that uses the css-only parallax so I thought using it on a new website shouldn't cause any problem, but now I can't get it to work because I need an overflow / hiding effect on an image with parallax effect. The effect is applied on some decorative elements too. Chrome works all the way, overflow or not. Safari doesn't work at all for all elements because my scrolling element is not the body. Firefox allows the decorative elements to move, but not the image which is the one wrapped with another overflow hidden... I'm lost!

Comment: @DavidLapointe I wasn't able to get a CSS-only parallax working for this particular project for all current browser versions, let alone even one- or two-year old browser versions, and unfortunately had to resort to a javascript solution. It's bad from an architectural and efficiency perspective, but was the only solution I could get working.